Why root user is getting 'Permission Denied' error creating any file inside dir owned by root
Why root user is getting 'Permission Denied' error creating any file inside dir owned by root
root@ubuntu:/sa/# touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied

~# df -h /sa
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/fuse       225T  201T   25T  90% /sa

# ls -ld /sa
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 Mar 23  2023 /sa

# lsattr /sa
lsattr: Function not implemented While reading flags on /sa/jour
lsattr: Function not implemented While reading flags on /sa/mount
lsattr: Function not implemented While reading flags on /sa/scratch
lsattr: Function not implemented While reading flags on /sa/snap

# cat /etc/passwd |grep -i root
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash


You've provided no OS/release & file-system details.. You do mention ubuntu-touch which is the Ubuntu Phone OS (it's now called Lomiri, but was Ubuntu Touch in the past).   Even a root user cannot touch or make changes to a RO file-system and other file-system reasons..

/dev/fuse: This is managed by a userspace program that does not care about you being root.
From https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html, emphasis is mine.

default_permissions
By default FUSE doesn’t check file access permissions, the filesystem is free to implement its access policy or leave it to the underlying file access mechanism (e.g. in case of network filesystems). This option enables permission checking, restricting access based on file mode. It is usually useful together with the ‘allow_other’ mount option.

